# Whats the R equivalent of the following Excel operation

Tags: r, excel

I have two column, col1 and col2, and I have the following formula in excel under col3

```
col1    col2    col3
0       0       0     
1       0       1
0       1       1
0       0       0
1       1       1
0       0       0
```

Assuming col1 is cell A1

```
C2 formula: =A2
C3 formula: =IF(A3=1,1,IF(B2=1,0,C2))
```

I could only achieve the first part,

```
df$col3 <- ifelse(df$col1 == 1, 1, 0)
```

How can I do this in R, assuming my data frame is called 'df'

Comment: I am not able to figure out how to reference the previous cell

Comment: @VincentGuillemot: i think the problem here is that the function is recursive and may depend on previous cell values,  so vectorization is hard to do, I would go for a good old for-loop...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a simple for-loop :

```
df <- read.csv(text="col1,col2,expectedCol3
0,0,0     
1,0,1
0,1,1
0,0,0
1,1,1
0,0,0")

df$col3 <- NA # initialize column
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(i == 1){
    df$col3[i] <- df$col1[i]
  }else{
    df$col3[i] <- ifelse(df$col1[i] == 1, 1, ifelse(df$col2[i-1]==1,0,df$col3[i-1]))
  }
}

# are expected and calculated identical ?
identical(df$col3,df$expectedCol3)
# > TRUE
```

Comment: Beautiful and Simple!! Loved the use of identical function also. Thank you so so much!

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr::lag()` function:

```
df <- read.table(text = "col1    col2    col3
0       0       0     
1       0       1
0       1       1
0       0       0
1       1       1
0       0       0", header = TRUE)

library(dplyr)
result <- df %>%
  # C3 formula: =IF(A3=1,1,IF(B2=1,0,C2))
  mutate(res = ifelse(col1 == 1, 1, ifelse(lag(col2) == 1, 0, NA)),
         res = ifelse(is.na(res), lag(res), res))

# C2 formula: =A2
result$res[1] <- result$col1[1]

result
#   col1 col2 col3 res
# 1    0    0    0   0
# 2    1    0    1   1
# 3    0    1    1   1
# 4    0    0    0   0
# 5    1    1    1   1
# 6    0    0    0   0
```

Comment: Nice! lag function is something new to me

Answer (score 1):

Your C3 formula is an or-operation on col1 and col2. As formula:

```
col3 = col1 OR col2
```

So basically do an or-operation:

In R:

```
col1 <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0)
col2 <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)
df <- data.frame(col1, col2)
df$col3 <- (df$col1 == 1 | df$col2 == 1) * 1
df
```

Multiplicating with 1 converts the logical values to numeric.

In Excel you could optimize col3 too:

```
C3 formula =N(OR(A2:B2))
```

Again: The N() formula transforms your logical values to numeric.

Comment: based on the data I gave you, your answer is correct, but it does not follow the logic in the formula, that is for case where col1=0 and col2 =1, col3 = 0 ( given previous col3 row is not 1).  Thanks for the answer

Comment: Right, but if there are only 0s and 1s and your result isn't ambivalent or based on a more complex logic you always can use a logical operation. :-)

Comment: Can't argue with that :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
 df=data.frame(col1=c(0,1,0,0,1,0), col2=c(0,0,1,0,1,0))

 # shift B column to get "previous" value in every row.
 df$col2_prev=head(c(NA,df$col2),-1);

 df$col3 <- ifelse(is.na(df$col2_prev), 
                     df$col2,  
                     ifelse(df$col1 == 1, 1, 
                           ifelse(df$col2_prev == 1, 0, df$col2)
                           )
                  )

 df[c("col1","col2","col3")]

  col1 col2 col3
1    0    0    0
2    1    0    1
3    0    1    1
4    0    0    0
5    1    1    1
6    0    0    0
```